# Is panelGroup allowed inside selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is this kind of "nesting" of `panelGroup` inside `selectOneMenu` allowed in JSF?

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="MOUNT" itemLabel="Local directory" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="AS3" itemLabel="Amazon S3" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="FTP" itemLabel="FTP site" />
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ConfigBean.rackspace}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="RCF" itemLabel="RackspaceCloud"/>
  </h:panelGroup>     
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The 4th `selectItem` is never rendered, no matter if `ConfigBean.rackspace` is `true`.

I also tried `p:outputPanel` instead of `h:panelGroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap it in `c:if` but it won't rerender the selectitem if you change rackspace in your bean.

```
<c:if test="#{ConfigBean.rackspace}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="RCF" itemLabel="RackspaceCloud"/>
  </c:if>
```

Remember that JSTL components execute only during create view so you would not be able to add 
`<f:selectItem itemValue="RCF" itemLabel="RackspaceCloud"/>` based on the condition in your bean for subsequent POSTS.

Comment: Are you getting some error ? What is the value of ConfigBean.rackspace after bean is created ?

Comment: Very important: declare JSTL core taglib as follows `<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">`. Not `<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">`! Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `<h:panelGroup` for that... and you better not use `<c:if` for that (INMO its an overkill)

Instead just use `f:selectItems` and load it conditionally in the server side...

Comment: for example : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-listbox-example/ you can work with arraylists too , populate conditionally it inside a `@PostConstruct` (instead of the getter...)

Comment: OK, got it. However, this solution is no good for me since I have other components that I want to exclude, not just this one. Thakns.